# how to compare the values got from variable_get

Tags: php, drupal

I am getting some values from variable_get . Now I need to check if particular value say ('hello') is present in values got from (variable_get) or not? How can I check this? I tried using in_array() but it doesn't work.

I am using the following code:

```
 $restrict_ip_list = variable_get('restrict_ip_address_list', array());
```

I am getting some set of values as 127.0.0.1; then I am using:

```
$visitip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Now I need to check whether or not `$visitip` is present in `$restrict_ip_list`.

Comment: Please name the programming language you are using and provide a short example of the code you wrote. Please also supply the full error message.

Comment: can you provide a var_dump from $restrict_ip_list?

Comment: restrict_ip_sanitize_ip_list(variable_get('restrict_ip_address_list', '')). I used this. this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used this restrict_ip_sanitize_ip_list(variable_get('restrict_ip_address_list', '')).  This gives values of ips stored inrestrict ip module in the array format.Then used in_array to check my ips is present or not. This works for me.

```
$ip_addrss =  restrict_ip_sanitize_ip_list(variable_get('restrict_ip_address_list', '')).
    if(in_array($visitorip,$ip_addrss)) {
                print_r($visitorip);
             }
```